# Keyboard animation is working only for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

I am working on the iOS application with Swift 4. In that project I created the dynamic TextFields. And I added UIScrollView when we click on the TextField the scrollview should move upside while the keyboard  appears and the scrollview should movie down when Keyboard disappears. The below code is working fine only when the first click is happen. From the second time onwards it is not working. When I edit the TextField keyboard is appearing but the scroll is not moving upside.

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var constraintContentHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

var activeField: UITextField?
var lastOffset: CGPoint!
var keyboardHeight: CGFloat!
```

In ViewDidLoad()

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

            // Add touch gesture for contentView
            self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(returnTextView(gesture:))))



@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if keyboardHeight != nil {
            return
        }

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height

            // so increase contentView's height by keyboard height
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.constraintContentHeight.constant += self.keyboardHeight
            })

            // move if keyboard hide input field
            let distanceToBottom = self.myScroll.frame.size.height - (activeField?.frame.origin.y)! - (activeField?.frame.size.height)!
            let collapseSpace = keyboardHeight - distanceToBottom

            if collapseSpace < 0 {
                // no collapse
                return
            }

            // set new offset for scroll view
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                // scroll to the position above keyboard 10 points
                self.myScroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.lastOffset.x, y: collapseSpace + 10)
            })
        }
    }


    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.constraintContentHeight.constant -= self.keyboardHeight

            self.myScroll.contentOffset = self.lastOffset
        }

        keyboardHeight = nil
    }





 @objc func returnTextView(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        guard activeField != nil else {
            return
        }

        activeField?.resignFirstResponder()
        activeField = nil
    }



    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        activeField = textField
        lastOffset = self.myScroll.contentOffset
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        activeField?.resignFirstResponder()
        activeField = nil
        return true
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue. What was the mistake I have done here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52171672/7734643

Comment: @RakeshaShastri thank you so much. Its working.